# How to exclude outliers individually for target & participant in R

Tags: r, outliers, standard-deviation

I'm (very) new to R, and I was wondering if I could get some help. I'd like to know how to exclude outliers that are two standard deviations for each participant's mean reaction time, and each target's mean reaction time and replace it with na.

My data looks like this:

```
ptp  rt    group   target
1    1094  E       dog
1    2100  E       hat
2    918   E       dog
2    1211  E       hat
3    1142  E       dog
3    1222  E       hat
1    10    W       dog
1    993   W       hat
2    897   W       dog
2    1078  W       hat
3    4002  W       dog
3    899   W       hat
```

I've calculated mean and sd for each participant and item

```
mean <- tapply(data$rt, data$target, mean)
sd <-  tapply(data$rt, data$target, sd)
mean <-  tapply(data$rt, data$ptp, mean)
sd <- tapply(data$rt, data$ptp, sd)
```

However, I'm super new at R, and working out the code to calculate two standard deviations from the mean (mean+1.96*SD and mean-1.96*SD) and converting all values that are outside of the range for both the participant to NA is a bit beyond me. There must be an easier way than doing this by hand! Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you so much,
Jen

Comment: are you going to accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

To get nice summary statistics you could use `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(rt ~ target + ptp, dat, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), sd196=sd(x)*1.96))
#   target ptp    rt.mean      rt.sd rt.sd196
# 1    dog   1  552.00000  766.50375 1502.34735
# 2    hat   1 1546.50000  782.76721 1534.22373
# 3    dog   2  907.50000   14.84924   29.10452
# 4    hat   2 1144.50000   94.04520  184.32860
# 5    dog   3 2572.00000 2022.32539 3963.75777
# 6    hat   3 1060.50000  228.39549  447.65516
```

For excluding (assuming you want to exclude whole observations for each `"target"`) you could set a subset of the data to `NA` using `ave()`.

```
dat$rt[with(dat, ave(rt, target, ptp, FUN=function(x) mean(x)/sd(x))) > 1.96] <- NA
#    ptp   rt group target
# 1    1 1094     E    dog
# 2    1   NA     E    hat
# 3    2   NA     E    dog
# 4    2   NA     E    hat
# 5    3 1142     E    dog
# 6    3   NA     E    hat
# 7    1   10     W    dog
# 8    1   NA     W    hat
# 9    2   NA     W    dog
# 10   2   NA     W    hat
# 11   3 4002     W    dog
# 12   3   NA     W    hat
```

To not exclude the whole participant don't include `ptp` into `ave()` and do:

```
dat$rt[with(dat, ave(rt, target, FUN=function(x) mean(x)/sd(x))) > 1.96] <- NA
```

**NB:** Check beforehand if names are not already assigned to functions. In your example you create a clash with the `mean()` and the `sd()` functions.

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(ptp = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), rt = c(1094L, 2100L, 918L, 1211L, 1142L, 1222L, 10L, 
993L, 897L, 1078L, 4002L, 899L), group = c("E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"), target = c("dog", "hat", 
"dog", "hat", "dog", "hat", "dog", "hat", "dog", "hat", "dog", 
"hat")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best and short way is to do:

```
library(dplyr)

data_2SD <- data %>% 
  group_by(ptp,target) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rt), ~replace(.x, abs(scale(.x)) >= 2, NA))
```

In your case, there are no such observations, grouped by each `ptp` and `target` that are bigger or smaller than two standard deviations of their mean reaction time:

Output:

```
> data_2SD
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   ptp, target [6]
     ptp    rt group target
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
 1     1  1094 E     dog   
 2     1  2100 E     hat   
 3     2   918 E     dog   
 4     2  1211 E     hat   
 5     3  1142 E     dog   
 6     3  1222 E     hat   
 7     1    10 W     dog   
 8     1   993 W     hat   
 9     2   897 W     dog   
10     2  1078 W     hat   
11     3  4002 W     dog   
12     3   899 W     hat
```